Pruning error cannot assign 'torch.cuda.FloatTensor' to parameter
I am struggling to work out why I'm getting this error when trying to apply the lottery ticket hypothesis to my model. Clearly this is happening during the pruning callback, and it seems like it's trying to save the previous weights as a parameter, but the value of a FloatTensor. I am quite at a loss of what to do.
  File "/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/u0977428/.micromamba/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/pruning.py", line 340, in apply_pruning                                                        
    self._apply_local_pruning(amount)
  File "/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/u0977428/.micromamba/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/pruning.py", line 311, in _apply_local_pruning                                                 
    self.pruning_fn(module, name=name, amount=amount)
  File "/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/u0977428/.micromamba/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/utils/prune.py", line 909, in l1_unstructured                                                                     
    L1Unstructured.apply(
  File "/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/u0977428/.micromamba/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/utils/prune.py", line 545, in apply                                                                               
    return super().apply(
  File "/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/u0977428/.micromamba/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/utils/prune.py", line 163, in apply                                                                               
    module.register_parameter(name + "_orig", orig)
  File "/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/u0977428/.micromamba/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 583, in register_parameter                                                               
    raise TypeError(f"cannot assign '{torch.typename(param)}' object to parameter '{name}' "
TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.cuda.FloatTensor' object to parameter 'weight_orig' (torch.nn.Parameter or None required) 

def main(config, ...):
    model = UNetLightning(
       ...
    )

    trainer_args = {
        "max_epochs": config.epochs,
        "precision": config.precision,
        "accelerator": config.accelerator,
        "callbacks": [],
        "gradient_clip_val": 1.0,
        "accumulate_grad_batches": 3,
    }
    initial_state = model.state_dict()  # Save initial state for pruning
    pruning_passes = 3  # Number of pruning passes to make

    for i in range(pruning_passes):
        print(f"Pruning iteration {i + 1}/{pruning_passes}")

        # Initialize the trainer with the pruning callback
        pruning_callback = ModelPruning(
            "l1_unstructured",
            amount=0.2,
            verbose=True,
            use_global_unstructured=False
        )
        
        # Apply pruning before moving the model to the GPU
        model.cpu()
        pruning_callback.on_fit_start(trainer=None, pl_module=model)
        
        trainer_args["callbacks"].append(pruning_callback)
        trainer = Trainer(**trainer_args)
        
        # Train the model
        trainer.fit(model, data_module)
        
        # Remove the pruning callback for the next iteration
        trainer_args["callbacks"].remove(pruning_callback)
        
        # Reset the model to initial weights
        model.load_state_dict(initial_state)

    # Final training pass without pruning to fine-tune the model
    trainer_args["callbacks"].append(checkpoint_cb) # Save the best model after fine-tuning
    trainer = Trainer(**trainer_args)
    trainer.fit(model, data_module)

    # Save the final model
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'final_pruned_model.pth')

